# Usar LIKE o LTRIM - SQL

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Estoy trabajando con oracle y C# en Visual Studio 2015 y tengo esta consulta

```
"SELECT * FROM TCTERCEROS WHERE TR_TERCERO = '" + TBNit.Text + "'"
```

Como puedo aplicar un LIKE o LTRIM, TBNit.Text es lo que se dijita en la caja de texto para consultar por ejemplo 123 pero en la BD esta 000000123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno el `LIKE` se usa con el signo `%` para que vaya capturando las entradas es decir:

este es si quieres que coincida todo

```
"SELECT * FROM TCTERCEROS WHERE TR_TERCERO LIKE '%" + TBNit.Text + "%'"
```

este es por si quieres que coincida al comienzo

```
"SELECT * FROM TCTERCEROS WHERE TR_TERCERO LIKE '" + TBNit.Text + "%'"
```

este es por si quieres que coincida al final

```
"SELECT * FROM TCTERCEROS WHERE TR_TERCERO LIKE '%" + TBNit.Text + "'"
```

Te dejo la guía de [LIKE en ORACLE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/like.php) para que te guíes mejor.

Espero te haya servido y la marques xD. **ReNiceCode...**

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio esta, muy amable
    "SELECT * FROM TCTERCEROS WHERE TR_TERCERO LIKE '%" + TBNit.Text + "'"

Comment: Con mucho gusto Bro siempre es un placer compartir conocimiento... ReNiceCode...

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta aceptada, soluciona tu problema sin embargo no se recomienda las consultas con concatenación de cadenas.

**Lo recomendable es usar [consultas parametrizadas](https://webprogramacion.com/12/adonet/consulta-de-actualizacion-sql-con-parametros.aspx)** en lugar de concatenar las cadenas. Sería algo como esto:

Creando una variable en la consulta: `@nombre_variable`.

```
"SELECT * FROM TCTERCEROS WHERE TR_TERCERO LIKE @nombre_variable";
```

Y la forma de usarla sería algo como esto:

```
comando.Parameters.Add("@nombre_variable", suTipoDato).Value = "%" + TBNit.Text + "%";
```

Con esto evita la **[Inyección SQL...](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)**

---

Solo por poner un ejemplo mas amplio:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    string Comando = "SELECT * FROM TCTERCEROS WHERE TR_TERCERO LIKE @nombre_variable";
    using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(Comando, con)
    {
        cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() {
                                ParameterName = "@nombre_variable",
                                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                Value = string.Format("%{0}%", TBNit.Text)
                            });

        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmnd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta);
            dataReader.Dispose();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dtgv.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agregale al texto TBNit.Text la funcion TRIMSTART.
Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
TBNit.Text.TrimStart('0')
```

Espero te ayude.
Saludos.